# rails assocation naming with table `ProductShow` and table `Product`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm confused about assocation table naming (for many to many asscoation)

now i have a model named ProductShow (in db it named product_shows)

also another model named Product (in db it named products)

now i want make a assocation table between them

this relationship between is

```
Product
   has_and_belongs_to_many :product_shows
ProductShow
   has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

what's the name for this assocation table?

also is there some way or tool can check this?

Comment: you need to explicitly explain how you want the associations setup. Do you want product_show to have many products. do you want products to have many product_shows. please elaborate explicitly :)

Comment: one product has many product_shows

and

one product_show has many products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to implement this using bi-directional `has_many` association.

```
class Product
  has_many :product_product_shows
  has_many :product_shows, :through => :product_product_shows
end

# table product_product_shows
#   product_id
#   product_show_id

class ProductProductShow
  belongs_to :product_show
  belongs_to :product
end


class ProductShow
  has_many :product_product_shows
  has_many :products, :through => :product_product_shows
end
```